# FB messenger. Is there any solution for not all users messages are being delivered(error 403 on the FB side)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, messenger

Hello I need a help with FB messenger. Chat bot has stopped responding for certain users(messages aren't delivered to our API server). Some users have no issues with sending messages and getting a response from our API(messages delivered, processed, etc). At the same time some users are experienced issues with with menu(error 403) or with button commands like "open detailed card". So it's not clear what issue cause this behaviour. We have tried to detach and attach FB page for a couple of times, recreate a page token - no luck for now. If there were an issue with page tokens then all users would be experienced the same issue. Is there any advice or solution which will make it clear where to look for an issue? Very appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved in a week by itself. I didn’t changed any settings on my side, so this was FB issue(90% sure). But it’s still unclear why different users have been experiencing a different behavior. If anyone had the same problem please share your experience and solutions here. Hope it will be helpful for somebody.